# How to save tableView custom cells to mutablearray

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableView with custom cells. 
Tableview is empty. 
I have "+" button which add my custom cell with label and textfield

Question: how can i save to mutable array textfield.text of all tableview cells when user pressed "+" button

Code of a "+" button here...

```
- (IBAction)addButtonPress:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {

    MYCustomTableViewCell *nextCell =[self.myTableViewProperty dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    if (!nextCell) {
        nextCell = [[MYCustomTableViewCell alloc] init];
    }
    MYCustomTableViewCell *previousCell =[self.myTableViewProperty dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    NSIndexPath *saveTextIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:myCustomCellCount inSection:1];

    // -- i can't get my customCell.textField.text
    previousCell = [self.createTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:saveTextIndex];
    NSLog(@"%@", previousCell.textField.text); ////- its null=(

    [cellArray addObject:nextCell];
    [self.myTableViewProperty reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add tag property to your `textField` that equals to you `indexPath` then you can simply access your textfields by their tag property.

Example:
Creating your new `customCell`

```
cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row;
```

Getting your cell's `textField`

```
MYCustomTableViewCell *previousCell =[self.myTableViewProperty cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UITextField *txtF = (UITextField*)[previousCell viewWithTag:myCustomCellCount];
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but i have some problems

Comment: when i want to access to text property like NSLog (@"%@",txtF.text); - app crash with Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableView text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x940b800'

Comment: Try with `[self.view viewWithTag: myCustomCellCount];`

Comment: it logs <UITableView: 0x9324600; frame = (0 0; 320 480); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8df08b0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8ddb710>; contentOffset: {0, -64}>
but i need "text"

Answer (score 0):

Please, have a look at the documentation [UITableViewDataSource Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource) before beginning. [This link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MVC.html) might be usefult as well. UITableView is just to display the content of your model (called datasource). So when `addButtonPress:` is called you should insert a data object into your datasource (e.g. an array) and tell the table view to reload it's content. In almost all cases `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` is ONLY called in `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. That's where a new table view cell representing your datasource's data objects is created. And there's no need to store the table view's cells in an array because that's done by the table view itself. When the user is done pressing the button you just iterate over your datasource array and read it's data objects.